# Upgrading moodle 3.4 to 3.9

Tags: upgrade, moodle

I am new to moodle and I need to do an upgrade. I have several questions first:

1. I have to upgrade from 3.4 to 3.5 and then to 3.9. Would I have to install all custom/aditional modules to 3.5 or can I do it just on 3.9.
2. This might be a dumb question, but I want to make sure I don't give anything for granted. In other to know which are custom/aditional modules I just have to go to the plugins view in administration and just copy the plugins that are on the section aditional plugins, right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

1. In general, you can get away with not installing all the custom plugins in 3.5. It is, in theory, possible that a 3rd-party plugin would choose to clean up their older upgrade steps, in the same way that core code does (which is why you can't jump direct from 3.4 to 3.9). I can't remember of any occasion where I've been caught out by a plugin doing that (and I've prepared hundreds of upgrades for different customers over the years). Note: you will see messages about plugins 'missing from disk' during the 3.5 upgrade step, but those should be fixed when you add the plugins back to the 3.9 code.
2. The list of additional plugins contains all of the plugins that are not part of the core Moodle code. It won't tell you about any custom changes that have been made to core Moodle files, but if you have simply been installing plugins and not messing around with core files (which is true in almost all cases), then you should be able to rely on the list.

Hopefully it goes without saying that you should always take a full database and moodledata backup before you start the upgrade, just in case there are problems (but, in my experience, they are fairly rare with normal upgrades).